# Access Log generation of deployed web application on Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS)

Tags: azure, web-applications, kubernetes, azure-aks

I have deployed a web application on Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS). I want to generate access logs (which include HTTP method, path, request body, if possible HTTP headers, and timestamp) of deployed web application and not of Kubernetes Cluster, Nodes and Pods. I have used Application Gateway, but it is creating logs of Kubernetes Cluster, Nodes or Pods. I have also used Log Analytics on Azure, but it is also not giving me required logs.

Comment: welcome to StackOverflow

Answer (score 1):

You need your application to generate those logs in some form. kubernetes doesnt provide networking logs. Easiest way is outputting to stdout, or, perhaps using Application insights. Another option is using something like Zipkin or Jaeger to capture those.